Which thin replacements for recessed light bulbs do I need?
My house has these canned recess lights that I just want to replace with the flush recess types. For instance the bulbs I use are currently like so:
https://a.co/d/5t9buk6
When I do some measurements I see the entire housing with trim is around 8”. For instance some pics:

Here is another pic measuring only the inside portion:

That part is close to 5.5 to 6 inches.
Im confused due to the size of these as I want to get these halo bulbs available also at home depot but dont know if I need to get 6”: https://a.co/d/8DBBOBr
Or the 8”: https://a.co/d/c2kN8pF
If I get the 6” it seems like the max size with trim is around 6.7” while I measure closed to 8” with my current cans. If I go with 8” it says 8.97” with the trim whereas my current cans with trim I measured closed to 8”.
Does it matter which one I get?

Another simpler option you might consider: In my old house, I didn't want to mess with removing/rewiring the recessed can sockets, so just removed the existing trim rings, and added flush LED retrofit disk lights similar to these: 

The trim style is independent of the can size to some extent, and you don't need to match the existing trim ring dimension unless it's important to cover a paint edge or oversize hole in the drywall. If you simply pull the trim ring down you can measure the can itself. They're held in place by friction or a simple spring. (Some comments say to measure the hole in the drywall, but that's not right either since some holes were cut sloppily. Measure the can.)
The 6" can is by far the most common or standard, and that's what you have. Buy for that.
